# When do prefer Dynamic Lookup over static lookup ? can we perform SCD type2 using dynamic lkp?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Dynamic cache refresh when new record get inserted, update or deleted from lkp src file. can we perform SCD type 1 and type 2 using dynamic lookup.

Answer (score 0):

In order to build SCD mappings, you need to check if the data is in your target. You can do that by simply reading the target as a source and using a `Joiner Transformation`. It's possible to use a dynamic `Lookup`, but that is not really needed.

Dynamic lookup will be useful if you need to wory about multiple data in your source for the same Business Key in a single mapping execution. This includes - but is not limited to - duplicates. For example if you load invoices from your source and for whatever reason invoice 123 is mentioned twice with different date, like:

```
| Row ID | Invoice No | Invoice Date
|    1   |    123     | 20210915
|    2   |    123     | 20210926
```

This is a case when by using `Dynamic Lookup Cache` it's possible to recognize that such row has already been inserted when processing row 1 and row 2 should be flagged as update. This wouldn't be possible otherwise.

`Dynamic Lookup Cache` might be also used to remove duplicates in scenarios where memory usage matters. It does not need to read and cache full set of data as in case of `Aggregator Transformation` or `Sorter Transformation`.

Comment: Can i perform dynamic lookup on Flatfile target